# How to iterate over a template-less variadic in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, variadic-functions, variadic

I was under the impression that I don't need a template in order to use variadics in C++. So in the following class, I have a method that accepts a variadic as its second variable. Now my question is: how do I iterate over the variadic?

```
class CoolClass{
    /** Other stuff go here */
    
    // my question is about this
    void variadic(X d, X others...){
        cout<<"Main is "<<d.value()<<endl;
        cout<<"Others are: "<<endl;
        for(const auto& o: { others... }){ // doesn't have to be const
            cout<<o.value()<<endl;
        }
    }
};
```

I tried running the code above and it doesn't work. I changed from `{ others...} to simply` others`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: AFAIK, you can use either templates or `va_list`

Comment: This is `C` feature which should be avoided in favor of tempted variadic arguments. It is still there to maintain backward comparability and as `C` extension.

Comment: I am not surprised that this doesn't work. Neither I, nor any suffering C++ compiler, will have any idea what this mysterious type called `X` is all about.

Comment: I wouldn't use va_lists. There is a reason C++ has typesafe templates

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Alternatives

Comment: Maybe you should use initializer list in that place. https://godbolt.org/z/GxhYT7bTa

Comment: *I was under the impression that I don't need a template in order to use variadics in C++* While true, the old c-style variadics are very limiting.  Better to use the new and improve C++ version.  Then you can do a fold expression like `(cout<<others.value()<<endl, ...);`

Comment: @MarekR initializer list solves my problem. Thanks. If you post as full response I can accept. And thanks Everyone else for making very valuable suggestions as well

Comment: `void variadic(X d, X others...)` is actually `void variadic(X d, X others, ...)`. so printf-like function.